# Convert string[] literal to string type literal

Tags: typescript, typescript2.3

I have an array of strings:

```
let foo = ["bar", "baz"];
```

I wish to perform something similar to `keyof type foo`, but for an array rather than an object:

```
type DESIRED_RESULT = "bar"|"baz";
```

Is there any way to convert all unique strings within an array to a type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` is inferred as `string[]`.
The array values don't enter the type system at all, so this is impossible.

If you put it in the type system, it [becomes possible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20foo%3A%20%5B%22bar%22%2C%20%22baz%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20bar%3A%20typeof%20foo%5Bnumber%5D%20%3D%20%22%22%3B):

```
let foo: ["bar", "baz"];
let bar: typeof foo[number] = "";
```

> Type `'""'` is not assignable to type `'"bar" | "baz"'`.