# elementof? Can I accomplish this?

Tags: typescript

Here's what I want to accomplish:

```
const names = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
type NameType = elementof names;  // This is not valid TypeScript
```

The behavior would be identical to this:

```
type NameType = "foo" | "bar" | "baz";
```

A solution will need to accomplish a few things.

- Provide an ordered enumerable sequence of strings.
- Expose the names as an addressable union of string literal types.
- Allow string maintenance without redundant source code edits.

Can TypeScript do this?

**Note:** This is not the same as [Convert string[] literal to string type literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686104/convert-string-literal-to-string-type-literal), because that question doesn't require a specifically ordered sequence of strings. Union types don't produce any way to get order information at run time.

Comment: `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` is not a type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string\[\] literal to string type literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686104/convert-string-literal-to-string-type-literal)

Comment: Possibly answered in [TypeScript String Union to String Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/typescript-string-union-to-string-array)

Comment: @SLaks `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` is indeed a type: a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) of [string literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).

Comment: @jcalz while that version works, the tuple type seems overkill, you don't really need tuple here .. just my 2c

Comment: Yeah it depends if the ordering of the elements is important to represent in the type level, which is up to @recursive to decide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the type of an item using a type query:

```
type NameType = typeof names[number];
```

The problem is that the type of `names` is `string[]`, so the above code just produces `string`.

You can infer the string literal types for the `const` using a helper function.

```
function array<T extends string>(p: T[]) : T[] {
  return p
}

const names = array(["foo", "bar", "baz"]);
type NameType = typeof names[number];   // The same as "foo" | "bar" | "baz"
```

Comment: This is perfect.  When did `typeof names[number]` get introduced.  The operand isn't a legal expression on its own.  I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: It's parsed as `(typeof names)[number]`, which is a valid type query.  It isn't `typeof (names[number])`, which is indeed an error.